# PHP - 8 decimals don't work

Tags: php

Here is a very simple code.

```
$a = 2000000.00000000;
$b = 0.00000001;

echo $a-$b; //output 2000000

I was expecting 1999999.99999999.
```

Can someone explain how to make it work ?
It would be very appreciate.

Comment: its not php, please read: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: Because [floats](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)

Comment: The earlier marked duplicate doesn't cover this particular issue, so  I've reopened the question.

Comment: you just want the extra rep  points you will now get :-) (jk)

Comment: @Dagon Yes, exactly, the extra zero rep per upvote ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can set the precision used when formatting floats as strings using the [`precision`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) ini setting, the default being 14:

```
ini_set('precision', 16);
echo $a - $b; // 1999999.99999999
```

Also, read [this article](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/06/the-php-floating-point-precision-is-wrong-by-default/) for a more generic breakdown on the subject.

Comment: just curious - what's the default?

Comment: @Dagon I think the default is 14.

Comment: @Dagon It is 14 as Jack stated, [**`This`**](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/06/the-php-floating-point-precision-is-wrong-by-default/) is an interesting read related to it aswell!

Comment: your right, found it on 2nd attempt. my google foo is weak today

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much for your help. I have set ini precision to 24 (i am storing in mysql in decimal(24,8). Now if i try i get (1999999.99999998998828232) as output. Using round($result, 8) don't work. Is there a way to limit it to 8 decimals ?

Comment: @BlackCrypto You can use `round()` to mitigate that.

Comment: what sort of cazy math you doing needing that precision?

Comment: @Dagon With PHP, the math *must* be crazy by definition :)

Comment: who knew `crazy string` was actully the model of the universe. any excuse for xkcd reference: http://xkcd.com/171/

Comment: @Jack Too easy :) Share the knowledge! Better than being a grungy old man haha!